# React Admin render resources based on permissions

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm building an admin interface with react admin on top of firestore.

Everything works great with the firestore dataProvider, but now I would like to handle permissions and, based on permissions, show a list of experts.

To achieve this I decided to implement a custom `Admin` with `AdminContext` and `AdminUI`.

The expected behaviour of my current implementation: if I'm not logged in, I'm first redirected to the login page and then based on permissions (`usePermission`), I decide what to render.

The real behaviour: AsyncResources gets the render even if not logged in and it will crash on the permissions check because is null.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <AdminContext authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={dataProvider}>
      <AsyncResources />
    </AdminContext>
  );
}
```

*Resources based on auth user permissions*

```
function AsyncResources() {
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const { loading, permissions } = usePermissions();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const experts = await firebase.firestore().collection("experts").get();
      const docIds: string[] = experts.docs.map((doc) => doc.id);
      setEmails(docIds);
    })();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <AdminUI layout={CustomLayout} theme={theme}>
        <Loading
          loadingPrimary="WePractice Admin UI"
          loadingSecondary="Loading..."
        />
      </AdminUI>
    );
  }

  if (permissions.admin) {
    return (
      <AdminUI layout={CustomLayout} theme={theme}>
        {emails.map((email) => (
          <Resource
            key={email}
            options={{ label: `${email}` }}
            name={`experts/${email}/requests`}
            list={RequestList}
            edit={RequestEdit}
          />
        ))}
        <Resource name={`experts`} list={ExpertList} />
      </AdminUI>
    );
  }

  return (
    <AdminUI layout={CustomLayout} theme={theme}>
      <Resource
        options={{ label: `${permissions.email}` }}
        name={`experts/${permissions.email}/requests`}
        list={RequestList}
        edit={RequestEdit}
      />
    </AdminUI>
  );
}
```

A solution to fix this is probably to to the following:

```
    <AdminContext authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={dataProvider}>
        <AdminUI layout={CustomLayout} theme={theme}>
            <AsyncResources />
        </AdminUI>
    </AdminContext>
```

In this case seems the `AdminUI` to do the authentication check and redirect to login.

The problem with this solution is that `Resources` **cannot** be wrapped by `div`, `fragments` or other components (I return an array), so in this case anything would be rendered.

Anyone has a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean cannot be wrapped?why?

Comment: <Resource> components can only be used as children of the <Admin> component.
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Resource.html

Comment: you can add isLoggedIn in usePermissions hook and add if statement checkking authentication and if its not logged in redirect to login page

Comment: I tried that but didn't really worked out. you mean the useAuthState hook?
<code>
const { loading, authenticated } = useAuthState(); \n
const redirect = useRedirect(); \n
if(!authenticated) { redirect('/login'); }
</code>
also trie the useAuthenticated() hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by moving the permissions logic at the upper level and using the Admin component.

*New implementation*

```
function App() {
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState<string[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const experts = await firebase.firestore().collection("experts").get();
      const docIds: string[] = experts.docs.map((doc) => doc.id);

      setEmails(docIds);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Admin
      catchAll={NotFound}
      authProvider={authProvider}
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
      layout={CustomLayout}
      theme={theme}
    >
      {(props) => {
        if (props.admin) {
          return [
            emails.map((email) => (
              <Resource
                key={email}
                options={{ label: `${email}` }}
                name={`experts/${email}/requests`}
                list={RequestList}
                edit={RequestEdit}
              />
            )),
            <Resource name={`experts`} list={ExpertList} />,
          ];
        }
        return [
          <Resource
            options={{ label: `${props.email}` }}
            name={`experts/${props.email}/requests`}
            list={RequestList}
            edit={RequestEdit}
          />,
        ];
      }}
    </Admin>
  );
}
```